# pure php or css - tree menu show only active nodes

Tags: php, menu, tree

I have build a tree menu in PHP, using a recursive function, wich works ok.
My menu structure is something like this:

Root
----Categ1
-------Categ11
---------Categ111
---------Categ112
-------Categ12
---------Categ121
---------Categ122
----Categ2
----Categ3
----Categ4

I am using bootstrap.

I need to show only the active nodes and the top level childrens. For my example **I need the menu to be opened like this** (I clicked on Categ 112 and subcategories of Categ12 to be hidden):
Root
----Categ1
-------Categ11
---------Categ111
---------Categ112
-------Categ12
----Categ2
----Categ3
----Categ4

The php function that generate my menu tree is:

```
/** show all subcategs of the selected category
 * @param $iCategIDSelected
 * @param null $arrCategs
 * @param bool $bIsOnTheLeaf
 * @return string
 */
static function getHTMLCategsForMenuBySelected($iCategIDSelected, $arrCategs=null, $arrAllParents=null){

    $bIsVisible = false;
    if($arrCategs == null){
        $oController = new ShopcategoriesController();
        $arrCategs = $oController->getShopCategories(0);
    }

    //find if we make the current node visible or not
    //if the current node id is on the parent's of the selected node then make it visible
    //take all nodes starting with root until the selected node
    if($arrAllParents==null){
        $arrAllParents = ShopcategoriesController::getParentsBySelectedCategID($iCategIDSelected,$arrCategs);
    }


    $sHTML = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">';

    foreach($arrCategs as $oneCateg){
        //find if is active or not
        $bActiveClass = '';
        if(in_array($oneCateg['id'],$arrAllParents)){$bActiveClass = 'active';}

        $sHTML .= '<li class="'.$bActiveClass.'">';
        $sHTML .= '<a href="'.URL::to('showcategory/'.$oneCateg['id']).'" class="list-group-item">'.ucfirst($oneCateg['name']).'</a>';
        if(count($oneCateg['subCategories'])>0){

            $sHTML .= ShopcategoriesController::getHTMLCategsForMenuBySelected($iCategIDSelected, $oneCateg['subCategories'],$arrAllParents);
            $sHTML .= '</li>';
        }else{
            $sHTML .= '';
        }
    }
    $sHTML .= '</ul>';
    return $sHTML;
}
```

The html structure is:

```css
ul.nav > li > a{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="menuCateg">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="active">
   <a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/1">Categ1</a>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active">
     <a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/2">Categ11 </a>
     <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class=""><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/3">Categ111</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/4">Categ112</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/18">Categ12</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
          <a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/6">Categ2</a>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li class=""><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/3">Categ121</a></li>
   <li class=""><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/4">Categ122</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  <li class=""><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/8">Categ3</a>
  <li class=""><a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:8000/showcategory/8">Categ4</a>
 </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in order to generate a menu tree with multilevel subcategories and show only the levels that have been selected (without all children from the tree).

THE TRICK were those lines:

```
 if( //if the current subcateg parentid is on the parent that must be active then show his children's otherwise do not
                ( in_array($oneCateg['parentid'],$arrAllParents)  && in_array($oneCateg['id'],$arrAllParents))
            )
```

Thank you for your help!

```
/** show all subcategs of the selected category
 * @param $iCategIDSelected
 * @param null $arrCategs
 * @param bool $bIsOnTheLeaf
 * @return string
 */
static function getHTMLCategsForMenuBySelected($iCategIDSelected, $arrCategs=null, $arrAllParents=null, $iLevel=0){

    $bIsVisible = false;
    if($arrCategs == null){
        $oController = new ShopcategoriesController();
        $arrCategs = $oController->getShopCategories(0);
    }

    //find if we make the current node visible or not
    //if the current node id is on the parent's of the selected node then make it visible
    //take all nodes starting with root until the selected node
    if($arrAllParents==null){
        $arrAllParents = ShopcategoriesController::getParentsBySelectedCategID($iCategIDSelected,$arrCategs);
        $arrAllParents[]=0;
    }

    $iLevel++;
    $sHTML = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked level_'.$iLevel.'">';

    foreach($arrCategs as $oneCateg){
        //find if is active or not
        $bActiveClass = '';
        if(in_array($oneCateg['id'],$arrAllParents)){$bActiveClass = 'active';}

        $sHTML .= '<li class="'.$bActiveClass.'">';
        $sHTML .= '<a href="'.URL::to('showcategory/'.$oneCateg['id']).'" class="list-group-item">'.ucfirst($oneCateg['name']).'</a>';
        if(count($oneCateg['subCategories'])>0){
            if( //if the current subcateg parentid is on the parent that must be active then show his children's otherwise do not
                ( in_array($oneCateg['parentid'],$arrAllParents)  && in_array($oneCateg['id'],$arrAllParents))
            ) {
                $sHTML .= ShopcategoriesController::getHTMLCategsForMenuBySelected($iCategIDSelected, $oneCateg['subCategories'], $arrAllParents, $iLevel);
                $sHTML .= '</li>';
            }
        }else{
            $sHTML .= '';
        }
    }
    $sHTML .= '</ul>';
    return $sHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a class when it's not active like `.not-active`.

```
.not-active{ 
   display: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure to have understood correctly your point but how about this way:

```
foreach($arrCategs as $oneCateg){
        //find if is active or not
        $bActiveClass = '';
        if(in_array($oneCateg['id'],$arrAllParents)){ //modified
           $bActiveClass = 'active';
        }else{
           $bActiveClass = 'not-active';
        }

        $sHTML .= '<li class="'.$bActiveClass.'">';
        $sHTML .= '<a href="'.URL::to('showcategory/'.$oneCateg['id']).'" class="list-group-item">'.ucfirst($oneCateg['name']).'</a>';
        if(count($oneCateg['subCategories'])>0){

            $sHTML .= ShopcategoriesController::getHTMLCategsForMenuBySelected($iCategIDSelected, $oneCateg['subCategories'],$arrAllParents);
            $sHTML .= '</li>';
        }else{
            $sHTML .= '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. My problem is, how to put .not-active class on generated menu (php function), because, in my case (if I click on "categ112") I have active class to: categ1, categ11 and categ112. That mean that is marked as active (not hidden or visible). I need to hide only: categ 121 and categ122 in my example.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It give me the idea and please find the solution below.